# getCachedNdefMessage returns null

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I am trying to read data from a NFC card. I use the following functions to get and read `NDEF` message, however I get null message.

I can get correct data length with `getMaxSize()` and `getType()` returns `org.nfcforum.ndef.type2` but `getCachedNdefMessage()` function returns null. What is more, I get `android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED` as an intent action insead of `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED`.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    IntentFilter ndefDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    IntentFilter techDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
    IntentFilter[] nfcIntentFilter = new IntentFilter[]{techDetected,tagDetected,ndefDetected};
    String [][] techListsArray = new String[][]{new String[]{
            Ndef.class.getName()
    }};

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    if(mNfcAdapter!= null) {
        mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, nfcIntentFilter, null);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "NFC not supported.");
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mNfcAdapter != null) {
        mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent: "+intent.getAction());

    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    printTagId(intent);

    if(tag != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "TAG detected.");

        String [] tagList =  tag.getTechList();
        if(tagList != null)
        {
            for (String str : tagList) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Tech " + str);
            }
        }

        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        readNDef(ndef);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "TAG is null.");
    }
}

private void readNDef(Ndef ndef) {

    try {
        ndef.connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "ndef type: " + ndef.getType());
        Log.d(TAG, "ndef maxSize: " + ndef.getMaxSize());
        Log.d(TAG, "ndef isWritable: " + ndef.isWritable());

        NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getCachedNdefMessage();
        if(ndefMessage != null && ndefMessage.getRecords().length > 0) {
            String message = new String(ndefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload());
            Log.d(TAG, "readNDef: " + message);
        }
        else{
            Log.d(TAG, "readNDef: NO Records.");
        }
        ndef.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "readNDef exception!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{ if(ndef != null) ndef.close(); } catch (Exception ex){}
}
```

And the output is like the following:

```
onNewIntent: android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED
Tech android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight
Tech android.nfc.tech.NfcA
Tech android.nfc.tech.Ndef
ndef type: org.nfcforum.ndef.type2
ndef maxSize: 1908
ndef isWritable: true
readNDef: NO Records.
```

As I read NDEF data by another free application, I am sure the card has NDEF type data. I cannot understand why I don't get `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED` instead of `TAG_DISCOVERED`. How can I get the data with NDEF format?

Answer (score 0):

This method may return **null** if the tag was in the **INITIALIZED** state as defined by **NFC Forum**, as in this state the tag is formatted to support NDEF but does not contain a message yet. See documentation [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html#getCachedNdefMessage()).

[image]

Comment: If so, what should I do in INITIALIZED state? Should I wait for sometime after onNewIntent triggered? What do you think?

Comment: you have to wait until tag receives the message. You could put check on that before calling getCachedNdefMessage.

Comment: I put some delay after getting Intent on onNewIntent callback, but still same.

Comment: Hope this link will help you https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-nfc-tags-with-android--mobile-17278